# How can I select the first and the last row for each set returned

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have the following data which I want to select as follows:
How can I modify the query to select the output as shown below?

```
select primary_id, timestamp, secondary_id,... from tablename where 
timestamp <= to_timestamp('2020-07-29 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
timestamp <  to_timestamp('2020-07-29 04:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
order by timestamp, secondary_id;
```

```
primary_id timestamp    secondary_id  attribute1  attribute2  ... -- I want to get
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1          2020/01/20   10            ...         ...         ... -- <- this
2          2020/02/28   10            ...         ...         ...
3          2020/03/01   10            ...         ...         ... -- <- and this
4          2020/04/08   20            ...         ...         ... -- <- this
5          2020/05/31   20            ...         ...         ...
6          2020/06/30   20            ...         ...         ...
7          2020/06/31   20            ...         ...         ...
8          2020/07/31   20            ...         ...         ... -- <- and this
```

Comment: Could you please explain clearly? Can you post your data and expected result as well

Comment: Each set in the sense, you need based on secondary_id?

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions to rank records having the same `secondary_id` by ascending and descending `timestamp`, and then use that information to filter in the first and last record per group:

```
select primary_id, timestamp, secondary_id, ... 
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by secondary_id order by timestamp asc ) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by secondary_id order by timestamp desc) rn_desc
    from tablename t
    where 
            timestamp <= timestamp '2020-07-29 00:00:00'
        and timestamp <  timestamp '2020-07-29 04:00:00'
) t
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
order by timestamp, secondary_id;
```

Note that you don't need `to_timestamp()` to convert these literal strings: you can use literal dates instead.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt help and response, GMB.I tried the above query, but it is taking a very very long time. On the other hand, the query I wrote earlier is taking only a few seconds. Any ideas on how to optimize this query? Currently, it would be faster for me to retrieve the entire dataset in Java and filter it there with how long the above query is taking. I would like to filter this at the Oracle end. Hence, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This also works when the value of secondary_id can be repeated in another group of rows, it simply checks if the current id is different from the previous or next row:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(secondary_id) over(order by timestamp asc ) lag_id,
        lead(secondary_id) over(order by timestamp asc) lead_id
    from tablename t
    where timestamp <= timestamp '2020-07-29 00:00:00'
      and timestamp <  timestamp '2020-07-29 04:00:00'
) t
where lag_id is null 
   or lead_id is null
   or lag_id <> secondary_id
   or lead_id <> secondary_id
order by timestamp, secondary_id;
```

Should be quite efficient as there's the same ORDER BY for both LEAD & LAG.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select primary_id, timestamp, secondary_id,... from
(select primary_id, timestamp, secondary_id,..., 
row_number() over (partition by secondary_id  order by timestamp) as rnk1,
row_number() over (partition by secondary_id  order by timestamp desc) as rnk2
from tablename where 
timestamp <= to_timestamp('2020-07-29 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and 
timestamp <  to_timestamp('2020-07-29 04:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) qry
where rnk1=1 and rnk2 = 1
order by timestamp, secondary_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Jim. Really appreciate the prompt help and response

Answer (score 0):

You could use **first_value** and **last_value**. These are analytics functions and can be used like in the demo below.

```
with demo_data ( primary_id, secondary_id, timestamp)as
( select 1, 10, date '2020-01-01' from dual
  union all
  select 2 ,10, date '2020-01-28' from dual
  union all
  select 3, 10, date '2020-02-03' from dual
  union all
  select 4, 20, date '2020-03-02' from dual
  union all
  select 5, 20, date '2020-03-15' from dual
)
, grouped_data as
( select primary_id,
         secondary_id,
         timestamp,
         decode(first_value(primary_id) over(partition by secondary_id order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ), primary_id, 'Y', 'N') first_row_in_group,
         decode(last_value(primary_id) over(partition by secondary_id order by timestamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING), primary_id, 'Y', 'N') last_row_in_group
  from   demo_data
)
select primary_id, secondary_id, timestamp
from   grouped_data s
where  first_row_in_group = 'Y' or last_row_in_group = 'Y'
/
```

Comment: Thank you Giliam

Comment: @Jared: Did this work for you and/or did you solve the issue?